# Save files with vscode on /var/www

Tags: 16.04, permissions, apache2

I'm trying to make some changes on a file on `/var/www/myproject/file.yml`

But it needs to save as sudo if I have to save from visual studio code.

`www-data:www-data`  is the owner of all files and directories; my user is added to `www-data` group, and the files have `rwx` as group permissions.

But i can't save without sudo, maybe it is because I can't pass throug `/var/www` to reach myproject folder?

How I can set the permissions to save without sudo?

Comment: Did you logout and in again after adding yourself to that group?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen post the solution as answer, it will help other users...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the Ubuntu has taken effected the new group added to your user, so you will need to log out and lo back in to have that change take effect.

So simply log out and back in to solve the permission issue.